# Reporting services - different formatting for patrent group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a raport in SSRS with several row groups, like:

[image]

Is it possible to specify formatting for one of the groups (the main one)? To achieve effect like this (lines of the main group are bold):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a List object (which is just a table with a single cell).

Set the Dataset to the same as the current table.

Set the grouping to Group By the field in Column 1.

Add the borders to the cell.

Drop the current table into the new List.

The list will break up the data by the column 1 group and then the current table will display the data as it does now.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do for this is I will make a child for sub report to handle the grouping where I will pass the parameters that will filter and display all of the data from a group.

then the parent class will be the one to calls it thru list and from there I can change the border style or size of list. in this way, the grouping will have a solid border per group